# Has George R. R. Martin described the color of Daenerys' pubic hair in any book?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I am curious about George R. R. Martin's attitude towards some of his characters. Cersei's pubic hair has been described (as blonde) by him more times than I find necessary, but his portrait of some other female characters seems to be not so "sexualized".

I don't remember any reference to Daenerys' pubis. Has GRRM described the color of Daenerys' pubic hair in any book?

Comment: Please, can you explain your downvote? This question is not too broad and it's not more "offensive" than many words and ideas you can find in A Song of ice and Fire.

Comment: You're not George R R Martin.

Comment: Can you tell us the purpose of this question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My down vote is because it is a bad question which I think shouldn't be on the site and the only reason I accept its existence is because of previous equally bad questions.

Comment: @mooz I am curious about GRRM's attitude about some of his characters. Cersei's pubic hair has been described by him more times than I find necessary, but his portrait of some other female characters seems to be not so "sexualized".

Comment: @Ginasius You're welcome to scour the ASOIAF pages using this [search tool](https://asearchoficeandfire.com/). From memory, I don't think the topic has been addressed since we only have Dany's own POV; and she's not like to mention her own pubes. Cersei/Brienne's pubic hair was only commented on by Jamie.

Comment: @mooz Is good to remember that the point of view in these novels always belongs to one of the characters and this can bias the perception of pubeses, as a masculine (heterosexual) POV may note pubeses more easilly. I didn't notice that point.

Comment: @mooz Please, can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Ginasius You're welcome to use my comment and expand it into a self-answer.

Comment: I fail to see how this is likely to attract "opinion-based" answers. Either there's a reference or there isn't. Yes/no.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is a bad question or in violation of the rules of the community. If X is true for Character A, why is it wrong to ask if X exists for Character B as well? The phrasing used in the question is polite and not offensive at all. We might think that the question is useless, boring, pedantic  but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: @Aegon I'd strongly argue that a question being useless and boring **does** make it a bad question. It just doesn't make it an off-topic question.

Comment: After seeing your comments below, I think perhaps you could still be a little more clear. Is there some more general suspected bias in George Martin’s writing that you’re trying to get at, and you think the difference in descriptions of their appearances is one sign of that? In that case, I think explicitly asking for evidence (or lack thereof) of this bias might reverse a lot of those downvotes. Then people can give whatever explanation they want. Part of the issue is that from reading this question, I can’t guess what sort of bias you’re seeking to identify.

Comment: Looks like someone's going "down". The vote count, I mean. What did you think I meant?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I didn't think you meant any other thing by writing "going down", because 1.- I always try to presume good faith 2.- I consideer this a serious question that I will not delete because is being useful to describe the exact levels of tolerance and harassment into this community. Of course, if some other people, not you, try to make fun implying salacious meanings of "going down" in this context i would find it tasteless and I would think that person being a coward because there's a situation of an individual opposed a crowd and a coward mocking him and taking sides for the crowd.

Comment: @Adamant Thank you for your suggestion. I've taken notes of every possitive suggestion and advice that I'v received, and I've tried to improve my question according to those advices. I added a motivation for my question, and I added an answer that copied one of the possible answer that other user suggested (with his permission). (follows)-->

Comment: @Adamant All those edits only brought more downvotes and more agressive and snarky comments from some users, when I've never used sarchasm nor innuendo in my questions or comments. I will keep editing this answer if I receive some advice, but I don't think that a posible bias by GRRM about sex in some of his characters can be never trully accepted as answer because, although it may be true, it would be a primarily opinion based answer.

Comment: @Adamant And I will not complain of downvotes, because people have right to do his will at it, but snarky and sarchastic comments, a lot more agressive than my comments are, when they become too many, tend to become "harassment". I've watched this kind of things in Twitter before.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

> Her other hand drifted down across the soft curve of belly, through the mound of fine **silvery-gold hair.**

(From *A Storm of Swords*, Daenerys II)

I think that's all you need.

Comment: I've searched the text, and it really makes reference to Daenerys: "Her other hand drifted down across the soft curve of belly, through the mound of fine silvery-gold hair,  and went to work between Dany's thighs", so I think that your answer is correct. Thanks a lot.